# I am having problems with rejecting negatives within my function

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, while-loop

I was doing a school assignment involving functions, it wasn't too hard until I learned I needed to reject negative numbers as variables. It doesn't reject the numbers and instead just skips the next variable and then will loop to a seemingly random variable random variables in the code when the function completes.

```
void InPatient()
{
    int DaysIn = 0;
    double DailyRate{};
    double MedicationCharges{};
    double ServiceCharges{};

    cout << "Please enter number of days patient stayed (Rounded up):" << endl;
    cin >> DaysIn;

    //I tried to use while statements to solve this problem and it hasn't worked

    while (DaysIn != 50000000000)
    {
        if (DaysIn >= 0)
        {
            cout << "Please enter hospital's daily rate as a decimal (Ex: .35, .265):" << endl;
            cin >> DailyRate;
        }

        else if (DaysIn < 0)
        {
            cout << "That is not a valid number in the system" << endl;
        }

        if (DailyRate >= 0)
        {
            cout << "Please enter medicine charges:" << endl;
            cin >> MedicationCharges;
        }

        else if (DailyRate < 0)
        {
            cout << "That is not a valid number in the system" << endl;
        }

        //I tried these else if statements to reject negative numbers and loop back but it just says "It doesn't work" and continues on.

        if (MedicationCharges >= 0)
        {
            cout << "Please enter service charges (for lab testing or whatnot):" << endl;
            cin >> ServiceCharges;
        }

        else if (MedicationCharges < 0)
        {
            cout << "That is not a valid number in the system" << endl;
        }

        if (ServiceCharges >= 0)
        {
            double DaysInFee = DaysIn / DailyRate;
            double HospitalBill = DaysInFee + MedicationCharges + ServiceCharges;

            cout << "Patient's Stay Fee: $" << DaysInFee << "\n";
            cout << "Medication Charges: $" << MedicationCharges << "\n";
            cout << "Service Charges: $" << ServiceCharges << "\n";
            cout << "Patient's total is $" << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << HospitalBill << " " << "today." << endl;
        }

        else if (ServiceCharges < 0)
        {
            cout << "That is not a valid number in the system" << endl;
        }
    }
}

void OutPatient()
{
    double MedicationCharges = 0;
    double ServiceCharges{};`

    //I've done something different down here, but it does the exact same thing

    while (MedicationCharges != 50000000000)
    {
            cout << "Please enter medicine charges:" << endl;
            cin >> MedicationCharges;
            cout << "Please enter service charges (for lab testing or whatnot):" << endl;
            cin >> ServiceCharges;
            
            double HospitalBill = MedicationCharges + ServiceCharges;
            cout << "Medication Charges: $" << MedicationCharges << "\n";
            cout << "Service Charges: $" << ServiceCharges << "\n";
            cout << "Patient's total is $" << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed <<       HospitalBill << " " << "today." << endl;
        

        if (MedicationCharges < 0)
        {
            cout << "That is not a valid number in the system" << endl;
        }
        
        //These just say "These don't work" but let's the code use them anyways.

        else if (ServiceCharges < 0)
        {
            cout << "That is not a valid number in the system" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

As stated in the code, I have used while and if statements to reject negatives, but it doesn't reject them.

Comment: Tip: If you have an `else` condition that is the logical inverse of the main `if` there is no need to re-state it. It's also odd that you're using both the `x = y` and `x = { y }` approach to initialization. Pick one, keep consistent.

Comment: What is the purpose of `50000000000`? That's a pretty large value for an `int`.

Comment: `5000000000` Is a safe guard incase the user inputs a number higher than what I had set it to before I posted this question. I need you to elaborate more on the `x = y` and `x = {y}` approaches, the way I had my code before posting was all variables = 0 until input, but that allowed code to activate and I didn't want it to activate early.

Comment: @Zer0Sp4c3 -- `50000000000` -- What is `sizeof(int)` on your platform?  You do realize that `int` has a limited range?

Comment: I fail to see how it's a safeguard against anything.

Comment: You should be taking your inputs separately, not in this single loop that isn't working the way you think it should be. And then there's the fact that you have a function with multiple purposes. It takes input **and** (attempts to) validate the input **and** does calculations. Write more functions. Make them singular in purpose.

Comment: I removed all `else` statements, the code does not feature the `x = {y}` approach you were talking about.

Comment: I mean specifically `double ServiceCharges{};` vs. `double ServiceCharges = 0.0;` where the `{}` is strange compared to the `int` definition literally the line above those.

Comment: If you want to guard against excessively high numbers, testing against a seemingly arbitrary value (that is wildly outside of the numerical range of `int`) is not the way to do it. There's a `>=` operator for a reason, as in `else if (MedicationCharges >= 1000000) { cout << "That seems high, even for a medical bill."; }`

Answer (score -1):

Add a `continue` in your `else if` blocks to restart the `while`-loop after an incorrect input

Alternatively, add a `break` or `return` statement to leave the loop or function. It depends what you want to do in the error case.

Comment: An answer that starts with maybe isn't an answer. It's a guess. If you aren't sure, don't answer.